# How to get a list of total number of loggedin users in every hour?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the total number of "ID User" that was logged in every hour! but what is happening sometime there is no users were loggedin in particular hour and I wanted to show that hour there is Zero users was loggedin.
I think to solve this I should of using a join table with all the hours that are between those two date that i am filtering by.
any suggestion for this problem?

```
SELECT 
      FORMAT(chDate,'yyyy-MM-dd H:00:00') as cDate ,
      count(ID) as nValue 
    FROM myDB.myTable 
    Where chDate > '2014-11-03 00:00:00' and chDate < '2014-11-03 4:00:00' 
    Group by FORMAT(chDate,'yyyy-MM-dd H:00:00')
```

The resault I got

```
     cDate                  nValue
2014-11-03 0:00:00            5
2014-11-03 3:00:00            8
```

The resault I want

```
     cDate                nValue
2014-11-03 0:00:00           5
2014-11-03 1:00:00           0
2014-11-03 2:00:00           0
2014-11-03 3:00:00           8
```

Comment: 'join table with all the hours' is probably best solution. You could use two tables - dates table (over some long period, we are using 30  years) and 24 records containing hour table.

Comment: I agree with you, but How i could use dates table that is what i am looking for .. do you have any example? I wanted a list of hours bettween two dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT convert(datetime,'2014-11-03 00:00:00') dates
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(hh, 1, dates) dates
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  dates < dateadd(hh,-1,'2014-11-03 4:00:00'))
SELECT a.dates,
       Count(id)
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN myDB.myTable b
              ON convert(date,a.dates) = convert(date,b.dates) and DATEPART(hour,a.dates) = DATEPART(hour,b.dates)
GROUP  BY a.dates
```

Comment: What is #temp is it compatible with Sql server 2008 r2? I got Invalid object name '#temp'.

Comment: @IamNumber5 change it to your tablename

Answer (score 0):

```
--example data
create table myTable (ID int, chDate datetime)
insert into myTable (ID, chDate) values (1, '2014-11-03 01:00'), (1, '2014-11-03 01:30'), (1, '2014-11-03 03:00'), (1, '2014-11-03 05:00')

SELECT DATEADD(hour, n.N, 0) as cDate
     , COUNT(t.ID) as nValue 
FROM dbo.Numbers n
     LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable t ON n.N = DATEDIFF(hour, 0, t.chDate)
WHERE n.N >= DATEDIFF(hour, 0, '2014-11-03 00:00:00') and n.N < DATEDIFF(hour, 0, '2014-11-03 4:00:00')
GROUP BY n.N
ORDER BY n.N
```

Note that this uses a [numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) but a date table would work just as well (better, even)

Example result:

```
2014-11-03 00:00:00.000 0
2014-11-03 01:00:00.000 2
2014-11-03 02:00:00.000 0
2014-11-03 03:00:00.000 1
```